# How to use OR filters in djcli?

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface

In [djcli documentation](https://pypi.org/project/djcli/) they explain you can filter models like this with the list command:

```
$ djcli ls settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is_staff=1 username email is_superuser
Auto-detected DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testproj2.settings
Auto-detected model=auth.User
-----  ------------  ---------
email  is_superuser  username
       True          newb
       False         13337noob
-----  ------------  ---------
```

But it does not show how to use the OR filter, ie. to list users that are either with `is_staff=True`, either `is_superuser=True`, is it possible ?

Otherwise, how do you recommend to propose a syntax for OR'ing filters so I can contribute to `djcli`?

Comment: It's likely that it's not supported, have you taken a look at `djcli`'s code to see if it implements it? Or maybe there's a ticket on their repo about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now (`30-11-2018 04:13 (UTC)`) **it's not possible.** 
**Why it's not possible ?**
If we look at the [souce code](https://yourlabs.io/oss/djcli/blob/master/djcli.py#L121), they've used the [**`filter()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) method to retrive results.

```
def ls(modelname, *args, **kwargs):
    """Search models

    kwargs are passed to filter.
    It shows all fields by default, you can restrict them with args.

    Show username and email for superusers::

        djcli auth.user is_superuser=1 username email
    """

    model = _model_get(modelname)
    models = model.objects.filter(**kwargs) # here the majot thing happens
    if not models:
        print('No result found !')
        sys.exit(0)

    _printqs(models, args)
```

So, if you execute a command like ,

```
djcli ls settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is_superuser=True is_staff=1 username email is_superuser
```

it will pass the `is_superuser=True is_staff=1` to the filter as `kwargs` which results a ***LOGICAL AND*** filter.

---

**How to do an `OR` filter in Django ?**
It can be done by using [**`Q()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and [**`|`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#or) operator
example:

```
MyModel.model.objects.filter(Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What'))
```

---

**Now what ??**
**Solution-1.** As [**@schillingt**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1637351/schillingt) mentioned, raise a ticket or PR to their repo regaurding the issue

**Solution-2.** Edit the source code
create a new fucntion, **`ls_OR()`** as,

```
from django.db.models import Q


def ls_OR(modelname, *args, **kwargs):
    """Search models

    kwargs are passed to filter in LOGICAL OR fashion.
    It shows all fields by default, you can restrict them with args.

    Show username and email for superusers::

        djcli auth.user is_superuser=1 username email
    """

    model = _model_get(modelname)
    or_filter = Q()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        or_filter |= Q(**{key: value})
    models = model.objects.filter(or_filter)
    if not models:
        print('No result found !')
        sys.exit(0)

    _printqs(models, args)
```

and now try with new command **`ls_OR`** as

```
djcli ls_OR settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is_superuser=True is_staff=1 username email is_superuser
```

**Solution-3.** Create a copy version of orginal package
I'm not sure about the License or leagel stuffs.
**Step-1**: Clone the [repository](https://yourlabs.io/oss/djcli)
**Step-2**: Edit the **`djcli.py`** file by adding the **`ls_OR`** function which is I mentioned in **Solution-2** section
**Step-3**: uninstall older version of **`djcli`** from your environment by **`pip uninstall djcli`**
**Step-4**: install our own `djcli` by **`python setup.py install`**
**Step-5** : start using **`ls_OR`** command :)

---

**Conclusion**
I would recommend `Solution-1`. If you're in a hurry go for `Solution-3`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** 
@JPG is right. I hadn't understood the question. My wrong answer:

I looked at their [code](https://yourlabs.io/oss/djcli/blob/master/djcli.py#L121). It is like when you want to filter out objects to delete. All you pass as named arguments to the command line is passed to the OR as `**kwargs`.

So as far as you can satisfy your query with passing simple keyword arguments as filter, you can filter `ls` command objects.

Example (I didn't test it):

`$ djcli ls settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL email username username=1337noob`

But for the fields you mentioned you might use `is_staff=1` instead of `is_staff=True` as it is in the comments and the documentation.